# Elastic Container Service: executing multiple commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, amazon-ecs

Is there any way of running multiple commands using the AWS Elastic Container Service's `execute-command` in the AWS CLI via a calling shell script?

I have managed to connect to my container successfully and create a Bash shell, as per the AWS documentation [1].

```
region="my-aws-region"
cluster="my-cluster"
task="my-task"
container_name="my-container-name"
cmnd="/bin/bash"

aws ecs execute-command \
    --region "$region" \
    --cluster "$cluster" \
    --task "$task" \
    --container $container_name \
    --command \""$cmnd"\" \
    --interactive
```

What I need to do is to run a script in the container from the Bash shell.

I have not been able to find any examples of something like this - they all just show the creation of the shell but do no more with it.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

[1] See https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/execute-command.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible. I could find no way of supplying parameters to the AWS Elastic Container Service's `execute-command` and so had to abandon this change.

Answer (score 0):

Once you are in an interactive `bash` shell, you really don't need an example of "how to run a script on an ECS task" you just need an example of how to run a script in a bash shell. Stop searching for "how to do this in an ECS task" and just search for "how to do this in a Linux shell".

Just like a bash shell on any other Unix/Linux server, you would run a shell script by simply typing the path to that shell script, and pressing . For example if there is a script named `my-script.sh` in the `/home` directory, you would run it by typing `/home/my-script.sh` and pressing `<Enter>`.

Comment: I'm trying to run the script from a calling script outside of the container. The calling script connects to the container and then runs the script in the container.

The issue I'm facing is that I don't seem to be able to supply parameters to the script in the container.

Comment: You are executing `/bin/bash` in interactive mode. Those specific arguments for `ecs execute-command` are specifically for opening up an interactive bash prompt that you would then type into manually. If you are trying to run a script completely automated, then remove the `--interactive` argument, and change `/bin/bash` to whatever the path of your script is.

Comment: Thanks for this. If I remove the `--interactive` argument, I get a message saying 'Missing required parameter in input: "interactive"'. If I try `--non-interactive`, I get 'Interactive is the only mode supported currently'.

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest version of the AWS CLI installed? Regardless, even if you ran it in `--interactive` mode, specifying an actual script to run instead of an interactive bash prompt is the key change you need to make.

Comment: I am using the latest version of the CLI. I can specify the script name but I also need to supply parameters to it. The command seems to take the whole of the string I use, including parameters as the whole name of the command to execute. E.g. if I supply the command `myscript.sh param1`, the process seems to try and execute a script called "myscript.sh param1", rather than "myscript.sh" and supplying param1.